# Deserialize a Dictionary (JSON) to a swift object

Tags: json, swift, swift3, deserialization

I'm trying to build a login function (POST method) and the resultant is a JSON with user details and few other details. I have created a class with all the fields I need to use from the result of POST call. But I'm facing an issue with deserialzing the json to the object of the class. Can some one help me with this. (I have seen similar questions on SO and tried  solving using the solution. I have tried converting the json to string and then to swift object using `var UserDetails = UserDetails(json:jsonString)`
 )

**My code:**

```
class UserDetails {
    let token:String
    let agent_id: Int
    let user_id:Int
    let company_id:Int
    let affliate_Id:Int
    let role_id:Int
    let username: String
    let surname:String
    let lastname:String

    init(token:String,agent_id: Int,user_id:Int,company_id:Int,affliate_Id:Int,role_id:Int,username: String,surname:String,lastname:String) {
        self.token = token;
        self.agent_id = agent_id;
        self.user_id = user_id;
        self.company_id = company_id;
        self.affliate_Id = affliate_Id;
        self.role_id = role_id;
        self.username = username;
        self.surname = surname;
        self.lastname = lastname;
    } }
```

**My controller class:**

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
                guard data != nil else {
                    print("no data found: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        NSLog("Login SUCCESS");
                        let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                        prefs.set(username, forKey: "USERNAME")
                        prefs.set(udid, forKey: "UDID")
                        prefs.synchronize()
                        print("Response: \(json)")

                        //var jsonString = NSString(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)! as String
//when I tried to do the above statement, an error is thrown. Cannot convert value of type NSDictionary to expected argument type Data
                        //var person:UserDetails = UserDetails(json: jsonString)

                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)// No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                        print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                    }
                } catch let parseError {
                    print(parseError)// Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                }
            }

            task.resume()
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
  "user": {
    "token": "ABCDEFGHI",
    "agent_id": 0,
    "user_id": 151,
    "company_id": 1,
    "affiliate_Id": 0,
    "role_id": 1,
    "username": "testman1",
    "surname": "Test",
    "lastname": "man",
  },
  "menu": [
    { .....
```

Can someone help me in solving this. Tia

Comment: Add your json response here in question.

Comment: @NiravD updated the question with JSON response. Please have a look

Comment: You should avoid using foundation classes (NSDictionary etc) and use Swift types.  So, `if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any]`

Comment: @Paulw11 hi Paul. I tried changing the code to `[String:Any]` and then convert the json response to string. But still the same error. `Cannot convert value of type [String:Any] to expected argument type Data`

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't an answer, it was just a general comment

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh okok. Sorry misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using Foundation classes (`NSDictionary` etc) and use Swift types.

I also suggest you add a failable initialiser to your `UserDetails` class that accepts a dictionary:

```
class UserDetails {
    let token: String
    let agentId: Int
    let userId: Int
    let companyId: Int
    let affliateId: Int
    let roleId: Int
    let username: String
    let surname: String
    let lastname: String

    init?(dictionary: [String:Any]) {

        guard let token = dictionary["token"] as? String,
            let agentId = dictionary["agent_id"] as? Int,
            let userId = dictionary["user_id"] as? Int,
            ...  // And so on 
        else {
            return nil
        }

        self.token = token;
        self.agentId = agentId;
        self.userId = userId;
        self.companyId = companyId;
        self.affliateId = affliateId;
        self.roleId = roleId;
        self.username = username;
        self.surname = surname;
        self.lastname = lastname;
    } 
}
```

and in your completion block:

```
 do {
     if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any] {

         if let userDict = json["user"] as [String:Any] {
              guard let userObject = UserDetails(dictionary:userDict) else {
                  print("Failed to create user from dictionary")
                  return
              }
              // Do something with userObject
         }
     }

  } catch let parseError {
```

I also took the liberty of removing the _ from your properties because _ are icky

Comment: Hi Paul. I copied your code and I got this error near guard statement `Excepted else after guard condition` and near else `Expression required`

Comment: Yeah.  My braces were messed up.  I was editing just as you were commenting

Comment: Why is it going into print statement even though I have the output? `print("Failed to create user from dictionary")`

Comment: Which output? Are you getting a valid user object?  Have you set a breakpoint and single-stepped through to see what is going wrong?

Comment: yes. I have tried. I printed the json and can see the result. I think its going wrong in this statement `if let userDict = json["user"] as? [String:Any] {`  https://postimg.org/image/y4utnpxjt/

Comment: You can see that `userDict` has a value, so that line is ok.  If you aren't getting a value for `userObject` then that initialiser is failing.  Set a breakpoint and single step through the `guard` statement.  See which `let` is failing

Comment: Yeah. I checked it . And there was some error in the naming of a variable. so it is throwing an error. Thanks Paul. And can I pass this object to another view controller or do I have to do it by variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129325/discussion-between-paulw11-and-asn).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to use Swift native `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary` also batter if you define your init method of `UserDetails` with single parameter of type `[String: Any]`.

```
class UserDetails {
    var token:String = ""
    var agent_id: Int = 0
    var user_id:Int = 0
    var company_id:Int = 0
    var affliate_Id:Int = 0
    var role_id:Int = 0
    var username: String = ""
    var surname:String = ""
    var lastname:String = ""

    init(userDic: [String: Any]) {

        if let token = user["token"] as? String, let agent_id = user["agent_id"] as? Int,
            let user_id = user["user_id"] as? Int, let company_id = user["company_id"] as? Int,
            let affliate_Id = user["affliate_Id"] as? Int, let role_id = user["role_id"] as? Int,
            let username = user["username"] as? String, let surname = user["surname"] as? String,
            let lastname = user["lastname"] as? String {

                self.token = token;
                self.agent_id = agent_id;
                self.user_id = user_id;
                self.company_id = company_id;
                self.affliate_Id = affliate_Id;
                self.role_id = role_id;
                self.username = username;
                self.surname = surname;
                self.lastname = lastname;
        }

    }
}
```

Now simply call this init method from your json response like this.

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any], let userDic = json["user"] as? [String: Any]{
     let userDetails = UserDetails(userDic: userDic)
}
```